# (Linux terminal or iTerm) How do I block select to delete(or edit)

Tags: shell, terminal, iterm2, iterm

This is not that important function though, how do I block select (to edit) at the terminal? For example, when you have the following command and I want to erase the middle one (nano)

`apt-get update && apt-get install nano && apt-get install emacs`

How can I select that command instead of just presssing down the delete key?

In case of common text editors such like sublime or notepad, you can press shift + <- or drag with your mouse to do that. how can I do that in terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

personally, when I need to write a long command,  I press `ctrl-x ctrl-e` to write it in my editor (my setting is vim).

If you want to do some navigation on command line, for example the default emacs bind, you can:

```
alt-b  #to go back a word
alt-f  #to go after a word
alt-d  #to del a word (after cursor)
ctrl-w #to delete a word before cursor
```

with some shell(e.g. zsh), you can even go to some certain character in the line, like vim's `f/F`